# Conditional rendering of icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do the conditional rendering for the Favstar icon only if the id's match (tested in `getMasterId` function. Any idea what's wrong? no icon is ever appearing on the screen and no errors in the console.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {collections} from "./data.js"
import {assets} from "./data.js"
import {FontAwesome, FaStar} from "react-icons/fa"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
           collectionsarr: collections,
           assetsarr: assets,
           clickedassets: []
        }
    }

    handleAssetsClick(id){
      const clickedassetsdata = this.state.assetsarr.filter(asset => asset.collectionId === id)
      this.setState({
        clickedassets: clickedassetsdata
      })
    }

    makeMaster(idclick){
      const themasteridnr = this.state.clickedassets.filter(masterpot => masterpot.id === idclick)[0].id
      const newcollections = this.state.collectionsarr.slice()
      const index = this.state.clickedassets.filter(masterpot => masterpot.id === idclick)[0].collectionId - 1
      newcollections[index].masterAssetId = themasteridnr
      this.setState({   
        ...this.state,
        collectionsarr: newcollections
      })
    }

    getAssetPath(masterAssetId){
      const asset = this.state.assetsarr.find(x => x.id === masterAssetId)
      console.log(asset.path)
      return asset ? require(`./${asset.path}`) : ''
    }

    getMasterId(assetnr){
      let index = (this.state.collectionsarr || []).findIndex(item => {
        return item.masterAssetId === assetnr;
      })
    
      return index != -1;
    }
  
  render(){
  return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>Sitecore coding challenge</h1>
            
            <div className="left">
              {this.state.collectionsarr.map(element => 
                <div key={element.id}>
                  <p onClick={()=>this.handleAssetsClick(element.id)}>{element.name}</p>
                  <img src={this.getAssetPath(element.masterAssetId)} alt="pic"/>
                  <br></br>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>

            <div className="right">
                {this.state.clickedassets.map(asset => 
                  <div key={asset.id}>
                    <img src={require(`./${asset.path}`)} alt="pic"/>
                    <p>{asset.name}</p>
                    <p>{asset.id}</p>
                    <button onClick={() => this.makeMaster(asset.id)}>Make master!</button>
                    <p>icon "this is the master</p>
                    
                    {asset.id === this.getMasterId(asset.id) && <FaStar />}
                    
                    <br></br>
                  </div>
                )}
            </div>
          </div>
        )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: getMasterId() is not returning an id. 
getMasterId() is returning true or false depending on whether index is different or equal to -1, respectively.
I think what you want is: 

  getMasterId(assetnr){
      let index = (this.state.collectionsarr || []).findIndex(item => {
        return item.masterAssetId === assetnr;
      })
    
      return index;
    }

Comment: @fjplaurr: still nothing appears...